# Need help sorting out my JOIN statements for multiple sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I will be up front and say I'm aware this is a messy query. The database is not managed by me so some of the relations are long and complex. It's a hosted EMR so I have very minimal access as to what SQL commands I can use. For instance I cannot have anything before the first SELECT statement. Then there is the fact that SQL is just something I know a tiny bit about so these reports get pushed on me and I'm not SQL expert.

That said I'm trying to pull in 3 separate queries for answer to questions we have on a form. I'm not sure how to bind these with the correct join and I have no doubt there is a better way to do it.

Here is my existing Query:

```
Select Distinct C.client_id,
  C.first_name,
  C.last_name,
  CV.rev_timein,
  Q1.answer,
  Q2.answer,
  Q3.answer

From Clients C,

(
    Select  C2.client_id as client_id,
      Answer.answer as answer
    From Clients C2
      Inner Join ClientVisit On C2.client_id = ClientVisit.client_id
      Left Join SavedVisitAnswer On SavedVisitAnswer.clientvisit_id =
        ClientVisit.clientvisit_id
      Left Join Question On Question.question_id = SavedVisitAnswer.question_id
      Left Join Category On Question.category_id = Category.category_id
      Left Join FormVersion On Category.form_ver_id = FormVersion.form_ver_id
      Left Join Forms On Forms.form_id = FormVersion.form_id
      Inner Join Answer On SavedVisitAnswer.answer_id = Answer.answer_id
    Where SavedVisitAnswer.question_id = '518722' And Forms.form_id = '336' And
      FormVersion.is_active = '1' And ClientVisit.rev_timein >= @param1 And
      ClientVisit.rev_timein < DateAdd(d, 1, @param2)
    GROUP BY  C2.client_id, Answer.answer
) Q1,

(
    Select  C3.client_id as client_id,
      Answer.answer as answer
    From Clients C3
      Inner Join ClientVisit On C3.client_id = ClientVisit.client_id
      Left Join SavedVisitAnswer On SavedVisitAnswer.clientvisit_id =
        ClientVisit.clientvisit_id
      Left Join Question On Question.question_id = SavedVisitAnswer.question_id
      Left Join Category On Question.category_id = Category.category_id
      Left Join FormVersion On Category.form_ver_id = FormVersion.form_ver_id
      Left Join Forms On Forms.form_id = FormVersion.form_id
      Inner Join Answer On SavedVisitAnswer.answer_id = Answer.answer_id
    Where SavedVisitAnswer.question_id = '518727' And Forms.form_id = '336' And
      FormVersion.is_active = '1' And ClientVisit.rev_timein >= @param1 And
      ClientVisit.rev_timein < DateAdd(d, 1, @param2)
    GROUP BY  C3.client_id, Answer.answer
) Q2,

(
    Select  C4.client_id as client_id,
      Answer.answer as answer
    From Clients C4
      Inner Join ClientVisit On C4.client_id = ClientVisit.client_id
      Left Join SavedVisitAnswer On SavedVisitAnswer.clientvisit_id =
        ClientVisit.clientvisit_id
      Left Join Question On Question.question_id = SavedVisitAnswer.question_id
      Left Join Category On Question.category_id = Category.category_id
      Left Join FormVersion On Category.form_ver_id = FormVersion.form_ver_id
      Left Join Forms On Forms.form_id = FormVersion.form_id
      Inner Join Answer On SavedVisitAnswer.answer_id = Answer.answer_id
    Where SavedVisitAnswer.question_id = '518728' And Forms.form_id = '336' And
      FormVersion.is_active = '1' And ClientVisit.rev_timein >= @param1 And
      ClientVisit.rev_timein < DateAdd(d, 1, @param2)
    GROUP BY  C4.client_id, Answer.answer
) Q3


  Inner Join ClientVisit CV On C.client_id = ClientVisit.client_id
  Left Join SavedVisitAnswer On SavedVisitAnswer.clientvisit_id =
    ClientVisit.clientvisit_id
  Left Join Question On Question.question_id = SavedVisitAnswer.question_id
  Left Join Category On Question.category_id = Category.category_id
  Left Join FormVersion On Category.form_ver_id = FormVersion.form_ver_id
  Left Join Forms On Forms.form_id = FormVersion.form_id
  Inner Join Answer On SavedVisitAnswer.answer_id = Answer.answer_id

Where Forms.form_id = '336' And
  FormVersion.is_active = '1' And CV.rev_timein >= @param1 And
  CV.rev_timein < DateAdd(d, 1, @param2)
Order By C.last_name
```

The goal is to have the output for each client in the date range formated as such.

Client_ID, First Name, Last Name, Date-Time, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do three sub query for what you need. Also you don't need to filter in the last where clause because you already did it in the sub-queries. I tried to create simple solution for you. If you search three single answer for three specific question it should work for you:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom    DATE
DECLARE @DateTo      DATE
DECLARE @QuestionId1 INT
DECLARE @QuestionId2 INT
DECLARE @QuestionId3 INT
DECLARE @FormId      INT

SET @DateFrom       ='2018-11-01'
SET @DateTo         ='2018-11-30'
SET @FormId         =336
SET @QuestionId1    =518722
SET @QuestionId2    =518727
SET @QuestionId3    =518728

SELECT 
    C.client_id
   ,C.first_name
   ,C.last_name
   ,ClientVisit.rev_timein
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN SavedVisitAnswer.question_id = @QuestionId1 THEN Answer.Answer ELSE '' END) Answer1
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN SavedVisitAnswer.question_id = @QuestionId2 THEN Answer.Answer ELSE '' END) Answer2
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN SavedVisitAnswer.question_id = @QuestionId3 THEN Answer.Answer ELSE '' END) Answer3
FROM Clients C
INNER JOIN ClientVisit ON C.client_id = ClientVisit.client_id
INNER JOIN SavedVisitAnswer ON SavedVisitAnswer.clientvisit_id = ClientVisit.clientvisit_id
INNER JOIN Question ON Question.question_id = SavedVisitAnswer.question_id
INNER JOIN Category ON Question.category_id = Category.category_id
INNER JOIN FormVersion ON Category.form_ver_id = FormVersion.form_ver_id
INNER JOIN Forms ON Forms.form_id = FormVersion.form_id
INNER JOIN Answer ON SavedVisitAnswer.answer_id = Answer.answer_id
WHERE Forms.form_id = @FormId
AND FormVersion.is_active = '1'
AND ClientVisit.rev_timein >= @DateFrom
AND ClientVisit.rev_timein < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateTo)
GROUP BY 
    C.client_id
   ,C.first_name
   ,C.last_name
   ,ClientVisit.rev_timein
```

**EDIT** I removed all variables. including your @param1 and @param2. If you want to use them put them back and execute it:

```
SELECT 
    C.client_id
   ,C.first_name
   ,C.last_name
   ,ClientVisit.rev_timein
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN SavedVisitAnswer.question_id = 518722 THEN Answer.Answer ELSE '' END) Answer1
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN SavedVisitAnswer.question_id = 518727 THEN Answer.Answer ELSE '' END) Answer2
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN SavedVisitAnswer.question_id = 518728 THEN Answer.Answer ELSE '' END) Answer3
FROM Clients C
INNER JOIN ClientVisit ON C.client_id = ClientVisit.client_id
INNER JOIN SavedVisitAnswer ON SavedVisitAnswer.clientvisit_id = ClientVisit.clientvisit_id
INNER JOIN Question ON Question.question_id = SavedVisitAnswer.question_id
INNER JOIN Category ON Question.category_id = Category.category_id
INNER JOIN FormVersion ON Category.form_ver_id = FormVersion.form_ver_id
INNER JOIN Forms ON Forms.form_id = FormVersion.form_id
INNER JOIN Answer ON SavedVisitAnswer.answer_id = Answer.answer_id
WHERE Forms.form_id = 336
AND FormVersion.is_active = '1'
AND ClientVisit.rev_timein >= '2018-11-01' /*@param1?*/
AND ClientVisit.rev_timein < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2018-11-30' /*param2?*/)
GROUP BY 
    C.client_id
   ,C.first_name
   ,C.last_name
   ,ClientVisit.rev_timein
```

Comment: Just to be clear, your DECLARE and SET statements are just for cleanliness? I ask because I cannot use them as the interface I have access to requires SELECT to be the very first thing, I cannot even have white space before it. I'm going to give this a try though, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Bryan ,  I saw param1 and param2 in your script, because of that I thought you can use variables. Anyway, I have added another query with no variable including param1 and param2. Change the dates and and execute it.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. param1, param2 and param3 are generated by the web front-end so I have access to a total of 3 variables. As you can see they make it real easy to do reports(sarcasm).  I am getting an error with query and it's possible I may have to contact the EMR provider as I think it's a bug. It's telling me "Ambiguous column name 'Answer'. " and Answer isn't a column it's a table. Unless you have some insight I'm going to assume this is a bug in there interpreter.

Comment: @Bryan , So, you have Answer field in more than one table that you use in join. I have updated Answer as Answer.Answer. Try again.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is much simpler and makes a lot of sense.  I hope that as I work with this more it becomes easier and my queries less messy. I was actually hired on as a 'Programmer' and it turns out they really just wanted an SQL Report Writer.